# Design Editor in FlashBuilder

Tags: flash, flash-builder

I downloaded FlashBuilder 4.7.
    I tried a simple flex project (a button) but i can not find the  Design mode button . 
Well, how can I find it ?

Thanks,

Eugen

Answer (score 1):

Design view was removed from version 4.7 of Flash Builder. You'll have to stick with 4.6 if you need design view.

Comment: Thank for answer. What could be use in 4.7 as Design View ?